# Update Combo Box Value

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access VBA I'm attempting to update a combo box's value based on a query.

Code:

```
Function updateComboBox()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim user as string

    user = environ("username")

    strSQL = "SELECT [Name] FROM myQuery WHERE [UserName] = '" & user & "'"

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Me.MyComboBox = rs.Fields(0)
    End If
End Function
```

The error I get:

`You can't assign a value to this object.`

How can I change the current value of the combo box?

It may be important to note that the combo box is a list of values populated from a query. It happens to be the same query `strSQL` is using. It is important that users can still *choose* other names, but it defaults to their own.

**EDIT:**

I ended up doing the following work around to make this work:

I set the default property of MyComboBox to be =[myTextBox].

Form_OnOpen --> Update myTextBox's value based on query. Refresh form so combobox displays myTextBox's value.

Comment: Have you tried me.mycombobox.value=rs.fields(0).value

Comment: @Nathan_Sav yes, I get the same error sadly :/

Comment: Does `MyComboBox` have a multi-value field as its Control Source?

Comment: @HansUp no, it is a single value.

Comment: And the error occurs at the `Me.MyComboBox = ` line, correct?  In that case, what if you go into debug mode when the error happens and run this statement in the Immediate window? `Debug.Print Me.MyComboBox.Value`

Comment: @HansUp Yes the error occurs at that line. It comes back as the default value when I try to run the debug.print.

Comment: What do you have as the combo box's Row Source property.

Comment: @HansUp it is a table/query row source. I think that was the issue to be honest. I made a work around that works, will edit original post to show people what I did.

Comment: Assigning values on the form `open` event is better off performed in the `on_load` event

Answer (score 0):

use this

for single data Me.MyComboBox.AddItem(***)

for collection

```
   Me.MyComboBox.List = rs.Fields(0)
```